# Electronics Blogs and Podcasts

Tags: education

There are some great blogs out there for programmers (Joel on Software, Paul Graham's Essays, etc.). I would love to know about any similar quality content for electronics. Do you have any great blogs or podcasts you love?

(submit one answer for each blog)

Comment: dupe? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/meta-share-your-favourite-reads

Comment: @Endolith - Comments to that question now point out why it's not a dupe, and in any case, this question was started several months before the linked one.  There's rarely a need to link dupes on both posts, just vote-to-close the newer post as a dupe of the older one.  There are cases when the older question should be closed to leave the newer one, but those should be brought to Meta.

Comment: Also, you found this dupe this long after it left the front page.  Close votes expire, so if you want to clean up older stuff, flag it or bring it to Meta.

Comment: @Kevin: Linked questions show up in the Linked section on the right, regardless, so it could be helpful to include it since they're related.

Comment: @endolith - Sure!  It's definitely helpful. I was just trying to understand your reason for posting "dupe?" instead of "Related:"

Answer (score 26):

[Electronics Engineering Video Blog Podcast](http://www.eevblog.com/)(eevblog)

Comment: Be aware that David swears in many of his video blogs, so it may not be suitable for children, or even at work (without headphones).

Comment: ok I must break it to his fan base but my 6 year old neighbor girl could act much better than him. He seems so he is amazed by...I dont know...he is alive or whatever. But I could never take that guy seriously. Granted his material may be good (I would never know as he is unbearable) but hell he IS UNBEARABLE.

Comment: Dave is just enthusiastic, he loves electronics design at work and at home... and it comes through in his videos. I enjoy listening to them in the background whilst doing something else.

Comment: ok there is a difference between enthusiasm and plain old over acting. And his way of making the videos would put over actors to shame.

Comment: Absolutely, but at the end of the day Dave's an EE, not an actor. :)

Comment: Dave and I started a radio show together. We'll have a name for it soon! http://chrisgammell.com/2010/08/02/2nd-radio-show-with-dave-jones-of-eevblog/

Comment: @tronixstuff - Whether he is an EE or not doesn't do anything to mitigate the fact that his videos are just plain obnoxious.

Comment: Fair enough. However lately he seems to have toned it down a bit, and the blog #110 was excellent.

Answer (score 11):

[Chris Gammell's Analog Life](http://chrisgammell.com/)

Comment: My first podcast: http://chrisgammell.com/2010/07/11/podcast-1-introduction-and-circuit-analysis/

Late in the game but I thought I'd throw it in there.

Answer (score 10):

http://www.hackaday.com

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised that nobody mentioned The Fat Man and Circuit Girl:
http://www.fatmanandcircuitgirl.com/

I'd say it's more along the lines of Joel on Software, where they're really sharing a lot of information on things they've tried and how it's worked out, but the community goes above and beyond.  It's a very entertaining and educational group.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore?  Just a landing page now...

Answer (score 6):

http://www.soldersmoke.com/

A lovely little ham radio podcast that I've been listening to for years. I'm not a ham radio guy at all, so there's plenty of interest to the general technologist here.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of blogs that people use to talk about their own projects.
They may not be "general education" but you wil certainly learn something.
Some of my favorites:

- http://mightyohm.com/blog/
- http://projects.dimension-x.net/
- http://interactive-matter.org/

This one is more engineering oriented
 - http://www.eevblog.com/

Answer (score 5):

I'm enjoying The Amp Hour Podcast

http://www.theamphour.com/

From Dave Jones (EEVBlog) and [Chris Gammell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/404/chris-gammell)

Comment: listening to it now - it's great!
Love the banter, it's especially funny when Dave tries to get Chris to say solder properly! [sorry Dave - "soder" is definitely wrong :)] Dave's random swearing and outbursts are a refreshing change to the usual grey drabness found in tech land

Answer (score 4):

http://electricio.us/

Answer (score 4):

[Jack Ganssle's column](http://www.embedded.com/columns/archive/?content%5Ftype=bp) on embedded.com - and indeed, [embedded.com](http://www.embedded.com/) itself.

Also, the collection of [articles on his website](http://www.ganssle.com/articles-subj.htm).

Admittedly these are mostly (though not entirely) software-oriented - but specifically embedded software.

Answer (score 4):

Very inspiring:

[Make:Blog](http://blog.makezine.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Although rather infrequent [Adafruit Industries - Citizen Engineer](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/feed/adacast)

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
- http://www.eetimes.com/
- http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorials.php
- http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/Tutorials/Tutorials

Answer (score 3):

http://tinkerlog.com

Comment: Fireflies! Wow! I think I'm going to need a large number of chips and an equal number of ping-pong balls. (If you don't know what I'm talking about follow the link and look at the videos of synchronising 64 Fireflies)

Comment: Yeah, some kind lately soldered up 64 of them. Don't know if he is already finished ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Keith's Electronics Blog](http://www.neufeld.newton.ks.us/electronics/)

Answer (score 2):

[Flying Flux](http://flyingflux.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically electronics but plenty of projects:

[Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.hackedgadgets.com

Answer (score 2):

I feel a little self-serving by adding this one, but I write it and I do try to mostly put in useful information without too much commercial type content. http://blog.screamingcircuits.com. It's predominantly about how to avoid common design and layout things that trip a lot of people up when they get to the point of building a board.

Answer (score 2):

[self-promotion] http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com

Comment: Very good blog! Congratulations! One up vote.

Answer (score 1):

[Eric Archer's Site](http://ericarcher.net/) especially the Devices section.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever wanted to build your own Synth:

[Music From Outer Space](http://www.musicfromouterspace.com/)

Check out the Virtual Breadboard Designer under the Electronic Bubblegum section if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I have a new Blog, [www.mendingthings.com](http://www.mendingthings.com) not a lot of content yet but I will keep adding. Someone has already mentioned HackADay. That is a great blog.

Answer (score 1):

I have collected many blogs about electronics over the three years and I have made an aggregated list of RSS feeds available through [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user/12805417219521926745/label/public%5Felectronics). Most of the blogs in this list are already mentioned here here but you might encounter some less familiar ones. I have also linked this feed to a [twitter account](http://www.twitter.com/knurdstuff).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this, I've just Bookmarked it.

Answer (score 1):

Lattice Semiconductor (an FPGA company) has [this blog](http://latticeblogs.typepad.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This [one on reconfigurable computing](http://fpgacomputing.blogspot.com/) in FPGAs.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Brazil we have the Newton C. Braga Blog: http://www.newtoncbraga.com.br/

There are lots of articles and tutorials.

It's in portuguese, but you can try translate it.

Answer (score 1):

[Evil Mad Scientist Laboratory](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/)

Projects, electronics or otherwise. All very sciency.

Comment: recipes are good too, plum chutney...

Answer (score 1):

The site www.newtoncbraga.com.br has a lot of circuits in portuguese, but with the Language Tool box it can be translated into english (or other languages). Try it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ben Heck show](http://revision3.com/tbhs) has turned out to be a really great show about hacking electronics. He digs into existing electronics and mods them for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very nice electronics blog: http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/