# Electrical and electronic engineering magazines

Tags: reference-materials

What electrical and electronic magazines can be recommended in order get up-to-date information about the latest technologies? I would like magazines listing from hardware hacking to proper professional design.

Comment: Solution found. This is now about any magazines that might be interesting to to anyone on the site. I merged over all other useful answers and have made it a community wiki. I hope this gets the job done.

Answer (score 21):

Ones that I read frequently:

- [Nuts & Volts](http://www.nutsvolts.com/), great monthly with lots of microcontroller projects
- [Servo](http://www.servomagazine.com/), sister publication to N&V with focus on robotics
- [Circuit Cellar](http://www.circuitcellar.com), more professional than N&V, lots of great hardware info
- [Elektor](http://www.elektor.com/), just started distribution of English translation in US
- [Everyday Practical Electronics](http://www.epemag3.com/), British magazine full of construction projects

Comment: I like Circuit Cellar.  They have a digital version so you don't have piles of old magazines stacking up.

Comment: @tcrosley - So do Elektor and Nuts & Volts. And the others maybe too

Answer (score 16):

This one's easy, Make magazine http://makezine.com/magazine/

Comment: I like their blog too: http://blog.makezine.com/

Comment: Amen to that bro!

Comment: plus you can get a digital subscription - much cheaper than the paper-based version

Answer (score 11):

Everything by UnwiredBen and Vineeth are great, but dont forget online websites for the freshest hacks.

My particular favorite [Hack A Day](http://hackaday.com/) is a great resource

Answer (score 6):

Of the "free" ones, there are:

[EDN](http://www.edn.com/index-edn-ad.html?gotourl=http://www.edn.com/)

[EETimes](http://www.eetimes.com/)

[Electronics Product News](http://www.epn-online.com/)

I will give you a warning, however.  If you subscribe to any of these, they WILL send you lots of spam emails.  Do not, under any circumstances, give them your normal email address!

Answer (score 6):

I always like what they have to say in [Circuit Cellular](http://www.circuitcellar.com/).  I'm not sure how much "breaking" technology they have since they're not trying to sell you on new products like many other free EE magazines.  They definitely always have articles that seem relevant, immediately implementable in any designs I do, and more technical than other magazines targeted at hobbyists.

Answer (score 5):

http://hackaday.com/

Comment: Already been posted: http://chiphacker.com/questions/1763/what-are-the-best-hardware-hacking-magazines/2894#2894

Comment: Ah, that's odd. I'm sure I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 4):

Some mention the EEvblog. I'm sorry to say, but the EEVblog with it's rambling is all nothing but plain bla bla and nothing to learn. You better not copy he's schematics if you want to build something that work. He doesn't even know how to make an emitter follower that doesn't oscillate. (For the record, it's not the op-amp that causes this circuit to oscillate. It's the emitter follower itself who's oscillating. It would even oscillate without feedback.)

If you wanne seem him going down? Check out this one.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7UQVZaqxg0

Base stopper resistors? Huh? Anyone.

And apart from that. He sounds like a cat.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

[PCB Design and Fab](http://www.pcdandf.com/cms/)
[CircuiTree](http://www.circuitree.com/)
[PCB Design 007 (and its related online mags)
[SMT/EMS007](http://www.ems007.com/pages/ems007.cgi)

[ECN (Electronic Components News](http://www.ecnmag.com/)

[Power Electronics Technology](http://powerelectronics.com/)

[ESD (Embedded Systems Design)](http://embedded.com)(under EE Times)

[Evaluation Engineering](http://www.evaluationengineering.com/)

[Nasa Tech Briefs](http://www.techbriefs.com/) (publications on left side)

[RTC (Embedded stuff)](http://www.rtcmagazine.com/)

Element 14 Technology First Journal](http://www.pcbdesign007.com/pages/pcbdesign007.cgi)(I have a few issues but can't find a subscribe link, forget how I got it)

Answer (score 3):

[LEDs Magazine {electronic, free, good}](http://www.omeda.com/led)

[electronic design update](http://www.elecdesign.com/Subscribe/.) Also electronic, free, good

[electronic design](http://electronicdesign.com/) website. Mailout material offered.

As for "spam". Most reputable sites have a working opt out policy and the sort of mail they send is in ant case liable to be of high interest and relevance to electrical engineers and fellow travellers.  I'm happy to have such sent to my main mailbox, where I can filter into folders etc as desired.

More later ...

There are groups who manage dozens of magazines - electronic only and real-paper.

Answer (score 2):

There was a question relating to Blogs and Podcasts that somebody asked 6 months ago in a similar vein, some of the resources there might be of interest: [Electronics Blogs and Podcasts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/952/electronics-blogs-and-podcasts/)

Answer (score 1):

These are the ones I enjoy reading:

[Elektor](http://www.elektor.com/)

[Circuit Cellar](http://www.circuitcellar.com/)

[Nuts and Volts](http://www.nutsvolts.com/)

[Everyday Practical Electronics Magazine](http://www.epemag3.com/)

[Servo Magazine](http://servomagazine.com/)

[Silicon Chip](http://www.siliconchip.com.au/)

Answer (score 0):

[EE Power](http://eepower.com) (www.eepower.com). A digital publication in power electronics focusing on technical articles, market insights, and design trends from industry-leading electrical engineers. Offers full content RSS feeds and Apple News integration.

Comment: Not a complete answer.